# ABP - Getting Workstation Information (IP) of logged in user

Tags: angular, http, asp.net-core, .net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I'm working with ASP.NET Boilerplate Core and Angular.

On user-login, I need to identify the users workstation in some way. 
IP as the Identifier would be best. Since I use my application only in Intranet, the hostname might be sufficient too.
Best would be to keep this information in the session object.

Any ideas?

Thanks for the much appreciated help!

Comment: Do YOU have any ideas? What have you tried? For best results on this website post some code w/ specific queries; not a general problem statement.

Comment: Not yet... I'm trying to get Alper's solution working. Its a little different with .NET Core as it seems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot reach *Request* object from application services. You can only grab it from Controllers.
What you can do is creating a new class which implements **IAuditInfoProvider** and register the class to dependency injection.
(With *IsDefault* is set to *True*).

```cs
Component.For<IAuditInfoProvider>().ImplementedBy<WebAuditInfoProvider>().IsDefault();
```

Extend AuditInfo class and add the client name field

```cs
public string ClientName { get; set; }
```

The new class inherited from *IAuditInfoProvider*
There's a method to get the client computer name.

```cs
public class WebAuditInfoProvider : IAuditInfoProvider, ITransientDependency
{
    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }

    private readonly HttpContext _httpContext;

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new <see cref="WebAuditInfoProvider"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public WebAuditInfoProvider()
    {
        _httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
        Logger = NullLogger.Instance;
    }

    public void Fill(AuditInfo auditInfo)
    {
        var httpContext = HttpContext.Current ?? _httpContext;
        if (httpContext == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            auditInfo.ClientName = GetComputerName(httpContext);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Warn("Could not obtain web parameters for audit info.");
            Logger.Warn(ex.ToString(), ex);
        }
    }

    private static string GetComputerName(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        if (!httpContext.Request.IsLocal)
        {
            return null;
        }

        try
        {
            var clientIp = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] ??
                           HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
            return Dns.GetHostEntry(IPAddress.Parse(clientIp)).HostName;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I have not tested all these codes but it's a good guide to show you the starting points of the solution.

Also you can take a look the below issue...
https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/467